# Officer: power point slides with ggplot(s) AS IMAGES

Tags: r, ggplot2, officer

The code below creates a PowerPoint slide with a vector based ggplot-object, this works great.

Now I want the same slide, with graph *as image* (e.g. PNG, un-editable). I think this was possible using ph_with_gg(plot, resolution) etc., but that's now deprecated.

It can be achieved with copy/paste as image in PowerPoint, but that's tedious. My main reason is large datasets and powerpoint slowing down with too many individual objects.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(officer)
library(rvg)
library(magrittr)
data(iris)

read_pptx() %>%
  add_slide(layout='Title and Content',master='Office Theme') %>%
  ph_with('Iris Sepal Dimensions', location = ph_location_type(type="title")) %>%
  ph_with(dml( ggobj=
                 ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,col=Species)) +
                 geom_point()), location = ph_location_type(type="body")) %>%
  print('iris_presentation.pptx')
```

Answer (score 3):

In that case, you only need to not call `rvg::dml`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(officer)
library(magrittr)
data(iris)

read_pptx() %>%
  add_slide(layout='Title and Content',master='Office Theme') %>%
  ph_with('Iris Sepal Dimensions', location = ph_location_type(type="title")) %>%
  ph_with(
    ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,col=Species)) + geom_point(), 
    location = ph_location_type(type="body")) %>%
  print('iris_presentation.pptx')
```

You can read the documentation here: https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/articles/offcran/powerpoint.html#ggplot-objects-1

Comment: I actually missed that a plot can be used directly and will end up as an image. But great, thanks. I have a tendency to overthink things :-)

Comment: no problem, see https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/reference/ph_with.html for a complete list of supported objects with  `ph_with`